# gnuplot adds extra space after tab completion

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, gnuplot, tab-completion

On my Ubuntu 14.04, I installed gnuplot using `apt-get install gnuplot-x11`. It's working fine except that when I tab complete a filename, it adds and extra space which I need to manually delete. This is somewhat annoying. Is there any way to fix it?

```
gnuplot> pl 'embedded_attractor.dat ' w l
         warning: Skipping unreadable file "embedded_attractor.dat "
         No data in plot

gnuplot> pl 'embedded_attractor.dat' w l
gnuplot>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a confirmed bug: [look here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnuplot/+bug/1422839)

A workaround could be put in you `~/.bash_aliases` or `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias gnuplot='rlwrap -a -c gnuplot'
```

It works fine for me.

Comment: Doing this simply stops tab completion!

Comment: Strange, my tab completion works: it complete properly the filename, without extra spaces, and also adds the `'` to the end of the filename.

Comment: For me too the tab completion is not working at all!!! And also by removing the line from the bashrc does not help.